# mysqli_commit fails when select statement is added

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

**Problem:**

Unable to store data with mySQL stored procedure with `mysqli_begin_transaction`.

**Details:**

The below code will do simple `insert` and `select` using mysql stored procedure. Code runs fine *without* `select` statement. However once the `select` statement is added, it won't commit any data even the query returns success at PHP side.

**Snippets (PHP):**

```
$DB_DRRM_SQLI = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","", "sandbox_db");
mysqli_begin_transaction($DB_DRRM_SQLI);

$SQL_QUERY_CODE = "CALL SANDBOX_TEST()";
$DB_QUERY = mysqli_query($DB_DRRM_SQLI, $SQL_QUERY_CODE);


// ERROR REPORTING
if($DB_QUERY === false)
{
    echo mysqli_error($DB_DRRM_SQLI);
    mysqli_rollback($DB_DRRM_SQLI);
}
else
{
    echo 'success';
    mysqli_commit($DB_DRRM_SQLI);
}
exit;
```

**Snippets (mySQL Stored procedure):**

```
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO 
    `sandbox_table`
    (
        `SOME_STRING`
    )
    VALUES
    (
        'ABCDEFGHIJKL...'
    );

    SELECT 
        LAST_INSERT_ID() AS INSERTED_ID,
        'ABCDE...' AS OTHER_PARAMS; 
END
```

**Database (Table sandbox_table):**

1. RECORD_PRIMARY_ID (*Int - Auto increment*)
2. SOME_STRING (*Varchar - 500 length*)

**Spec:**

- PHP version: 5.6.14
- 10.1.8-MariaDB
- Storage Engine: *InnoDB*

**Notes:**

- If transaction is made at stored procedure works fine, but I need a PHP managed transaction to handle multiple query requests and response depending on the result of query.
- (It can be a possible last resort if there's no other solution, where I need to convert whole PHP code to stored procedure and need pass tons of parameter)

**Methods Tested:**

- Tried with other PHP version 7.0.9 with same result (10.1.16-MariaDB)
- Tested with new database with no other data except `sandbox_table`and above stored procedure.
- Tested without additional include libraries (tested with purely on above snippets).

Comment: How do you know that mysqli commit fails?

Comment: Why don't you do the transaction handling in the stored proc itself?

Comment: @Your Common Sense It won't save any record at `sandbox_table`, for this sample it should add single record with string "ABCDEFGHIJKL..." at `SOME_STRING` field.

Comment: @Shadow actually this is only a part of my code. In actual page php transaction hold the 3~4 stored procedure query. If one of request fails, it should rollback the whole transaction.

Comment: I've also tested the transaction in stored procedure side, it works fine, but I want the PHP managed transaction.

Comment: Have you tried fetching the results from the procedure before the commit? Wondering if there are buffered results peventing the commit completing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**

It was caused by **Commands out of sync** error at `mysqli_commit`. Seems the **mysqli** won't allow committing transaction while the query is open, which happens if you add `select` statement to above stored procedure.

So to handle this, it must close the query first or put the query to buffer.

**Snippets (PHP):**

```
// SQL Database
$DB_DRRM_SQLI = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","", "sandbox_db");
mysqli_begin_transaction($DB_DRRM_SQLI);

$SQL_QUERY_CODE = "CALL SANDBOX_TEST()";
$DB_QUERY = mysqli_query($DB_DRRM_SQLI, $SQL_QUERY_CODE);

// ERROR REPORTING
if($DB_QUERY === false)
{
    echo mysqli_error($DB_DRRM_SQLI);
    mysqli_rollback($DB_DRRM_SQLI);
}
else
{
    // Must free current query result before committing transaction
    @mysqli_free_result($DB_QUERY);
    @mysqli_next_result($DB_DRRM_SQLI);

    if(mysqli_commit($DB_DRRM_SQLI) === false)
    {
        echo mysqli_error($DB_DRRM_SQLI);
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'success';
    }
}
exit;
```